# Unsupported geometry type 'Unkown type' in Layer - Unable to load project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, geometry, loading

This is a seemingly simple issue but I can't seem to fix it. When I load my project in QGIS, I get an error message that says: "Unsupported geometry type 'Unknown type' in Layer ''. When I click "OK", it just appears again. No matter how many times I click "OK", it pops up and doesn't allow me to do anything. I can't even quit QGIS, I have to force quit.

Comment: Have you tried opening a new project and adding your layers manually in order to determine, which layer causes the issue?

Comment: Hi Erik, I know which layer it is, as it tells me in the error message. Still don't know what to do from there. The project has many layers (100+) and I don't want to have to create it over again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the layer from the .qgs file using a text editor?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to do that. Can you please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Make a copy of the .qgs, then open it using a text editor, search for the layer name you want to remove, study the file structure and then remove the parts which need removing.

Comment: Hi Erik, I tried to open it with textedit on my mac, but its unable to open the qgz file format. Am I missing something here? please advise? Thanks for your help!

Comment: .qgz is a zipped .qgs.

Comment: Hi Erik, can you or do you know of anyone who can help me with this? I managed to open the text file but am not 100% sure what to remove.